# MvxBind:Error - View type not found - fragment

Tags: google-maps, android-fragments, xamarin.android, google-maps-android-api-2, android-2.2-froyo

I'm trying to add map as a part of my activity.
Unfortunately when I put fragment among other control I got the following error:

```
 <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="250.0dp"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

> MvxBind:Error: 26.04 View type not found - fragment

I'm trying to start it with Android 2.3 device using:

- MonoDroid
- googleplayservicesfroyo12-12.0.0 -
  GooglePlayServicesFroyoLib.dll
- Mono.Android.Support.v4.dll

What could be the issue here?
TIA!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is simply MvvmCross being over-verbose on it's error reporting.

The underlying problem is simply that fragments are not `View`s in the sense of 'normal Android' - they don't inherit from `View` and they don't really get inflated in the same way as other `View`s do. I believe MvvmCross reports this as an error and returns `null` from it's `OnCreateView` method within its inflater factory - at which point the underlying Android infrastructure then inflates the fragment anyway.

So I believe this is an error message you can ignore for fragments.

---

**Note:** For 'normal' `View`s, this error message is valid - it's there to tell you that the View hasn't been inflated by MvvmCross, so we also won't be able to add any data-binding to it.